# Unit difference between \draw command and \draw command inside \foreach command

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to draw a two dimensional coordinate system with numbers in the axis. This is the code that I am trying:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand*{\TickSize}{2pt}%


\draw [-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (4.5,0);% x-axis
\draw [-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5);% y-axis

\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {%
    \draw ($(\x,0)+(\x,-\TickSize)$) -- ($(\x,0)+(\x,\TickSize)$)
        node [below,yshift=-2pt] {$\x$};
}

\foreach \y in {1,...,4} {%
    \draw ($(0,\y)+(-\TickSize,\y)$) -- ($(0,\y)+(\TickSize,\y)$)
        node [left,xshift=-2pt] {$\y$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But, from that, I am obtaining the following result:

[image]

Which I was not aspecting, since the numbers are going out of the axis. This solution was inspired from this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82210/tick-numbers-on-x-and-y-axis), and there, apparently, the author did not face this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The statement `\draw ($(\x,0)+(\x,-\TickSize)$)` is adding the `\x` coordinate twice, thus doubling the scale of the ticks and numbers placement.  Same on the `\y`.

And, as Torbjorn adds, the coordinates need not be calculated inside a `$` delimited phrase, but can be specified directly, in this case.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand*{\TickSize}{2pt}%


\draw [-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (4.5,0);% x-axis
\draw [-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5);% y-axis

\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {%
    \draw (\x,-\TickSize) -- (\x,\TickSize)
        node [below,yshift=-2pt] {$\x$};
}

\foreach \y in {1,...,4} {%
    \draw (-\TickSize,\y) -- (\TickSize,\y)
        node [left,xshift=-2pt] {$\y$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The coordinate calculations (`$`) are not needed here, just `(\x,-\TickSize)` is enough.